# Multiply dataframes with differnet lengths regarding columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, matrix-multiplication

I have two dataframes, the first one `df1` contains only one row :

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  8  9  5  0
```

and the second one has multiple rows , but the same number of columns:

```
   D  C  E  A  B
0  5  0  3  3  7
1  9  3  5  2  4
2  7  6  8  8  1
3  6  7  7  8  1
4  5  9  8  9  4
5  3  0  3  5  0
6  2  3  8  1  3
7  3  3  7  0  1
8  9  9  0  4  7
9  3  2  7  2  0
```

In real example I have much more columns (more than 100). the both dataframes has the same number of columns, and the same columns names, but the order of columns is different, as it's shown in the example. 
I should multiply two dataframes (matrix_like multiplication), except of I couldn't perform simple `df2.values * df1.values` because the columns are not ordered in the same manner, so for instance the second column of df1 *B* couldn't be multiplied at the second column of df2, because we find *C* instead of *B* at second column of df2 , while the column *B* is the 5th column in df2.

Is there simple and pythonic solution to multiply the dataframes, taking into account the column names ant not column index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df1[df2.columns]` returns a dataframe where the columns are ordered as in df2:

```
df1
Out[91]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  3  8  9  5  0

df1[df2.columns]
Out[92]: 
   D  C  E  A  B
0  5  9  0  3  8
```

So, you just need:

```
df2.values * df1[df2.columns].values
```

This will raise a key error if you have additional columns in df2; and it will only select df2's columns even if you have more columns in df1.

As @MaxU noted, since you are operating on numpy arrays, in order to go back to the dataframe structure you will need:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.values * df1[df2.columns].values, columns = df2.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), `df1` is converted to `Serie` by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print df1.ix[0]
A    5
B    8
C    9
D    5
E    0
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print df2.mul(df1.ix[0])
    A   B   C   D  E
0  15  56   0  25  0
1  10  32  27  45  0
2  40   8  54  35  0
3  40   8  63  30  0
4  45  32  81  25  0
5  25   0   0  15  0
6   5  24  27  10  0
7   0   8  27  15  0
8  20  56  81  45  0
9  10   0  18  15  0
```

If you need change order of final `DataFrame`, use  with [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print df2.mul(df1.ix[0]).reindex_axis(df2.columns.tolist(), axis=1)
    D   C  E   A   B
0  25   0  0  15  56
1  45  27  0  10  32
2  35  54  0  40   8
3  30  63  0  40   8
4  25  81  0  45  32
5  15   0  0  25   0
6  10  27  0   5  24
7  15  27  0   0   8
8  45  81  0  20  56
9  15  18  0  10   0
```

Another solution is reorder columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) `index` of `Serie` by `df2.columns`:

```
print df2.mul(df1.ix[0].reindex(df2.columns))
    D   C  E   A   B
0  25   0  0  15  56
1  45  27  0  10  32
2  35  54  0  40   8
3  30  63  0  40   8
4  25  81  0  45  32
5  15   0  0  25   0
6  10  27  0   5  24
7  15  27  0   0   8
8  45  81  0  20  56
9  15  18  0  10   0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, even if I marked another one as right one, because I found it more pythonic, your solution is interesting and works well too, so I upvoted it with a pleasure!